# Possible pattern in higher (mixed) partial derivatives of the function $f(x,y)=\exp(xy)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I was writing down the $4^{\mathrm{th}}$ degree Taylor polynomial of the function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^+, f(x,y)=e^{xy}$ around $(0,0)$ so I computed all the necessary partial derivatives:

$$\begin{aligned}f(x,y)&=e^{xy}\\\partial_xf(x,y)&=ye^{xy}\\\partial_yf(x,y)&=xe^{xy}\\\partial_{xx}f(x,y)&=y^2e^{xy}\\\partial_{yx}f(x,y)&=(1+y^2)e^{xy}\\\partial_{yy}f(x,y)&=x^2e^{xy}\\\partial_{xxx}f(x,y)&=y^3e^{xy}\\\partial_{yxx}f(x,y)&=(2y+xy^2)e^{xy}\\\partial_{xyy}f(x,y)&=(2x+x^2y)e^{xy}\\\partial_{yyy}f(x,y)&=x^3e^{xy}\\\partial_{xxxx}f(x,y)&=y^4e^{xy}\\\partial_{yxxx}f(x,y)&=(3y^2+xy^3)e^{xy}\\\partial_{yyxx}f(x,y)&=(2+2xy+2xy+x^2y^2)e^{xy}\\\partial_{xyyy}f(x,y)&=(3x^2+x^3y)e^{xy}\\\partial_{yyyy}f(x,y)&=x^4e^{xy}\end{aligned}$$ and it turns out only $\partial_{xy}f(0,0)$ and $\partial_{yyxx}f(0,0)$ are non-zero (with all possible permutations of the variables we derive with respect to). This computations and writing them down before plugging into the formula take some precious time on exams, so my question is:

> If we continue deriving further (since $f$ is of the class $C^\infty$) what can we conclude about the (mixed) partials?

My guess is that, since, for $(x_0,y_0)\in\Bbb R^2,$ $$e^{x_0y_0}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x_0y_0)^n}{n!},$$ if $x^p$ appears,it appears in the product $x^py^p.$

> Is that the case? If not, is it possible to reduce the amount of brute force computations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Due to
$$ e^{xy} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^ny^n}{n!} $$
on one hand, and on the other hand, by Taylor
$$ f(x,y) = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \sum_{\ell = 0}^\infty \frac 1{k!\ell!}\frac{\partial^{k+\ell}}{\partial x^k \partial y^\ell}f(0,0) x^ky^\ell $$
Comparison of the coefficients tells us that
$$ \frac{\partial^{k+\ell}}{\partial x^k \partial y^\ell}f(0,0) = 0, \qquad k\ne \ell $$
and
$$ \frac{\partial^{2k}}{\partial x^k \partial y^k}f(0,0) = \frac{k!k!}{k!} = k! $$